# How to write Cypher query for this case?

Tags: java, neo4j, cypher

I have a graph like below illustration.[image]

A WAR can PUBLISH multiple SERVICEs and also can DEPENDSON multiple SERVICEs.

My requirement is to get the dependent WARs for a given WAR.

I know how to write a query to get the first-layer dependency.

```
MATCH (w:WAR)-[:PUBLISH]->(s:SERVICE)<-[:DEPENDSON]-(otherWar:WAR)
```

My question is how to get multiple-layer dependency for a given WAR.

In this case, between war1 and war3, there are two PUBLISH/DEPENDSON relation. How can I describe this relation with variable length relationship?

Answer (score 3):

[UPDATED]

### Finding the ways one war depends on another

Assuming that the `PUBLISH` and `DEPENDSON` relationships always start from a `WAR` node and end at a `SERVICE` node, I believe this query will find all paths in which `war3` (ultimately) depends on `war1`.

```
MATCH p=(w:WAR {name:'war1'})-[:PUBLISH]->
  ()-[:PUBLISH|DEPENDSON*0..]-()
  <-[:DEPENDSON]-(otherWar:WAR {name:'war3'})
RETURN p;
```

Using the same sample data as presented by @GaborSzarnyas, the above query produces this result:

```
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| p                                                                                                                                                                          |
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| [Node[6]{name:"war1"},:PUBLISH[6] {},Node[9]{name:"s1"},:DEPENDSON[8] {},Node[7]{name:"war2"},:PUBLISH[10] {},Node[11]{name:"s3"},:DEPENDSON[11] {},Node[8]{name:"war3"}]  |
| [Node[6]{name:"war1"},:PUBLISH[7] {},Node[10]{name:"s2"},:DEPENDSON[9] {},Node[7]{name:"war2"},:PUBLISH[10] {},Node[11]{name:"s3"},:DEPENDSON[11] {},Node[8]{name:"war3"}] |
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

#### Finding the dependencies of a war

This query should find all distinct `WAR` nodes that depend on `war1`:

```
MATCH (w:WAR {name:'war1'})-[:PUBLISH]->()-[:PUBLISH|DEPENDSON*0..]-()<-[:DEPENDSON]-(otherWar:WAR)
RETURN DISTINCT otherWar;
```

The result is:

```
+----------------------+
| otherWar             |
+----------------------+
| Node[7]{name:"war2"} |
| Node[8]{name:"war3"} |
+----------------------+
```

Comment: While that works in this case, if the `w` :War was 'war3', it would match on paths to the other :WARs. As far as I can tell this kind of variable relationship would match to every war within the subgraph, and I don't think that quite meets the needs. 'war3' never published a service, so there are no :Wars that are dependent upon it.

Comment: @InverseFalcon Yes, I was in the middle of updating my answer to be more specific. Can you come up with a way the updated answer can go wrong?

Comment: Great edit, the MATCH looks good to me!  I was about to comment about showing the query for getting just the distinct dependent wars, but you beat me to it!

Comment: I like the hackishness and efficiency of this solution :-). I tried using undirected edges and `|` in the relationships, but it did not occur to me that you can add "just enough directionality" and have a path of `*0..`.

Answer (score 2):

Up to my knowledge, there is no way to create variable length paths on subgraphs, i.e. you cannot state something like `(){-[:PUBLISH]->(:SERVICE)<-[:DEPENDSON]-}*()`.

I reproduced your sample dataset with this code:

```
CREATE
   (war1:WAR {name: 'war1'}),
   (war2:WAR {name: 'war2'}),
   (war3:WAR {name: 'war3'}),
   (s1:SERVICE {name: 's1'}),
   (s2:SERVICE {name: 's2'}),
   (s3:SERVICE {name: 's3'}),
   (war1)-[:PUBLISH]->(s1),
   (war1)-[:PUBLISH]->(s2),
   (war2)-[:DEPENDSON]->(s1),
   (war2)-[:DEPENDSON]->(s2),
   (war2)-[:PUBLISH]->(s3),
   (war3)-[:DEPENDSON]->(s3)
```

If this is possible in your use case, you insert additional edges in the graph:

```
MATCH (w:WAR)-[:PUBLISH]->(s:SERVICE)<-[:DEPENDSON]-(otherWar:WAR)
MERGE (w)<-[:WAR_DEPENDS]-(otherWar)
```

And use these for traversing:

```
MATCH (w1:WAR)-[:WAR_DEPENDS*]->(w2:WAR)
RETURN w1, w2
```

This gives:

```
╒════════════╤════════════╕
│w1          │w2          │
╞════════════╪════════════╡
│{name: war1}│{name: war2}│
├────────────┼────────────┤
│{name: war1}│{name: war3}│
├────────────┼────────────┤
│{name: war2}│{name: war3}│
└────────────┴────────────┘
```

If you do not want to persist this edge, the trick is to run this in a single query and *not* commit the transaction:

```
MATCH (w:WAR)-[:PUBLISH]->(s:SERVICE)<-[:DEPENDSON]-(otherWar:WAR)
MERGE (w)<-[:WAR_DEPENDS]-(otherWar)
WITH otherWar AS w1
MATCH (w1)-[:WAR_DEPENDS*]->(w2:WAR)
RETURN DISTINCT w1, w2
```

This again results in:

```
╒════════════╤════════════╕
│w1          │w2          │
╞════════════╪════════════╡
│{name: war2}│{name: war1}│
├────────────┼────────────┤
│{name: war3}│{name: war1}│
├────────────┼────────────┤
│{name: war3}│{name: war2}│
└────────────┴────────────┘
```

Comment: I think this is a great solution, however it looks like you got the :WAR_DEPENDS relationship inverted. If `w`publishes a service that `otherWar` depends on, then otherWar is dependent upon w.

Comment: @InverseFalcon thank you very much for pointing that out -- it turns out that the last query was also wrong, as I passed both `war` and `otherWar` and reused them. This was obviously wrong (it gives only direct connections), so I fixed and tested the query.